# Java: counting data stored in a class

Tags: java

**Important:** This is kind of a repost of my last question, however there is specific information that makes the answers to it unable to be used in my program. Thank-you for those answers, and I'm sorry I goofed.

From the project instructions: **"Not use any dynamic data structures such as arraylists."** I also cannot change the variables within the class in any way.

I have the following class:

```
public class Job_16997761 {

  private int jobID;             // unique job identification number
  private int customerID;        // unique customer identification number
  private String registration;   // registration number for vehicle for this job
  private String date;           // when the job is carried out by mechanic
  private String day;            // day of the week that job is booked for
  private double totalFee;       // total price for the Job
  private int[] serviceCode;     // the service codes to be carried out on the vehicle for the job

  //Constructor
  public Job_16997761(int jobID, int customerID, String registration, 
          String date, String day, double totalFee, int[] serviceCode) {
      this.jobID = jobID;
      this.customerID = customerID;
      this.registration = registration;
      this.date = date;
      this.day = day;
      this.totalFee = totalFee;
      this.serviceCode = serviceCode;
  }

  //Get and set methods removed because irrelevant

}
```

The number at the end is just my student ID, it's required to be there so don't mind it. The program reads a bunch of data from a text file and stores it as a class using the following code in the main solution (not part of the class code):

```
public static void getJobFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Job_16997761[] job = new Job_16997761[0];
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the Job text file: ");
        jobFile = kb.next();
        Scanner jobScan = new Scanner(new File(jobFile));
        while (jobScan.hasNext()) {
            countC ++;
            jobScan.nextLine();
        }
        job = new Job_16997761[countC];
        countC = 0;
        while (jobScan.hasNext()) {
            String[] line = jobScan.nextLine().split(",");
            int[] tempArray = new int[line.length - 6];
            for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
                tempArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i + 6]);
            }
            job[countC] = new Job_16997761(Integer.parseInt(line[0]), Integer.parseInt(line[1]), 
                    line[2], line[3], line[4], Double.parseDouble(line[5]), tempArray);
            countC ++;
        }
    }
```

Part of the project is to create a new Job based on data inputted by the user. However each "day" can only have a maximum of 12 jobs assigned to it. I am unsure how to go about finding the number of jobs that are on x day. I don't want to use the File if I don't have to, but I'm unsure if that's possible at all.

Comment: create variables (one for each day) and increment them.

Comment: But how? I don't know how to get the data from the Job class as a whole.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of the question is totally wrong but couldnt you create variables like int monday inside your while loop and always when line[3].equals("monday") increment that counter and only if monday < 12 create a new Job object?

Comment: ...hm. That could work actually. I think I can do that, thank-you!